# how to capture a traceback in gevent

Tags: python, exception, gevent, greenlets

I've spawned a Greenlet and linked it to a callable. Some time later, the Greenlet fails with an Exception. The linked callable gets called. That's all great!

Here's the issue:

The traceback for the Exception appears on my console, as you'd expect. But I want do things with that traceback within the linked callable. How do I get access to that traceback within the linked callable?

(My first instinct was to use `traceback.extract_stack()`, but it turns out that provides a traceback for the linked callable itself and not for the Exception.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The traceback is intentionally not saved when the Greenlet dies. If it was saved, it would keep a lot of objects alive that are expected to be deleted, which matters especially if the object manages some resource (open file or socket).

If you want to save the traceback you have to do it yourself.

Comment: And THAT is an authoritative answer. Thanks, Denis.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Stephen Diehl's solution using `Greenlet.link_exception`.

```python
import traceback

import gevent

def job():
    raise Exception('ooops')

def on_exception(greenlet):
    try:
        greenlet.get()
    except Exception:
        err = traceback.format_exc()
        # Do something with `err`

g = gevent.spawn(job)
g.link_exception(on_exception)
```

Comment: You would spawn then link rather than create, link, and start? Is there any practical difference?

Comment: And does this address the concerns I raised in comments to Diehl's solution?

Comment: Well I guess theoretically the greenlet could crash before the link is created this way.

Comment: Did some testing, and it seems like it doesn't really address your concern. However it gets the entire stacktrace, but it will just contain some extra references too (like greenlet.get()). https://github.com/gevent/gevent/pull/589

Answer (score 1):

The `Greenlet` object should have an `exception` property that you can look at:

http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.exception

Comment: How would I get the traceback from that?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you grab the `exception` value of the Greenlet and throw it outside the Greenlet, for example `get` returns either the value returned or raises the internal exception.

```
import traceback
import gevent

def fail():
    return 0/0

gl = gevent.spawn(fail)

try:
    gl.get()
except Exception as e:
    stack_trace = traceback.format_exc() # here's your stacktrace
```

Should give you what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to get the traceback within a linked callable (e.g., foo = gevent.Greenlet(x); foo.link_exception(bar); foo.start(); <foo dies>; <now we're in bar()>) -- doing what you've suggested within bar() does not produce the traceback for the Exception as it was raised in foo, it produces the traceback for the Exception as it is raised in bar.

Comment: Perhaps you should paste your code up above, your issue seems to a scoping problem and it would be easier to debug if we could see how you are setting up your scopes.